# form is not responsive

Tags: wordpress, forms, twitter-bootstrap

i m using form manager to make form for my site in Twitter's Bootstrap theme in wordpress. my problem is that evry form i made from this and when i show it on page it is not responsive what should i have to do to make it responsive?

Here is how i show the form on my page:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide img-rounded">
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="active item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA01.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA02.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA03.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA04.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA05.jpg" /></div>
<div class="item"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/GRAAVAA06.jpg" /></div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span3"><a href="#"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/stoneOfMonth.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="span3"><a href="#"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/newArrivals.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="span3"><a href="http://graavaa.com/wp/downloads/"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/download.png" /></a></li>
    <li class="span3"><a href="http://graavaa.com/wp/contact-us/"><img src="http://graavaa.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/locateUs.png" /></a><br/>
<div class="hidden-phone">[form form-1]</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any preview of the code of the generated form? or a preview of the complete page.

Comment: u can view it on:
http://graavaa.com/wp/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "Contact Form 7" plugin, you will then need to style the form like this (Liquid responsive form)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul>
                <li>[form shortcode 1 class:span12]</li>
                <li>[form shortcode 2 class:span12]</li>
                <li>[form shortcode 3 class:span12]</li>
                <li>[form shortcode 4 class:span12]</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to give the form fields a class of span12, and the whole form needs to be inside a div with the class "row-fluid"

If you just want to hide the form on mobile devices, then the code you have is correct! Double check you have all the responsive JS/CSS bootstrap files, also test it on a mobile device and not a desktop.